# Trying to use updateOne() in MongoDB, but it's not updating the document or giving me an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to add a value obtained from a calculator to a user's document in the database, however it's not showing any error or updating the document, the page just loads forever and I'm not sure why. Below is the code where I'm trying to update:

```
   router.post('/tdeecalculator', function(req, res){
        User.updateOne({email: "testtesttest@test.com"}, {$set: {tdeenumber: req.body.tdee}})
    });
```

And below is my user schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tdeenumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    ormnumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

The document in MongoDB shows as this:

```
_id: 60c217c26c83903ee454c2c5
name: "testtesttest"
email: "testtesttest@test.com"
password: "$2a$10$zQ4Jk3KKCjjNTyY0Z48/X.JkPO0J5lfV6j4gqTR1sLmqxKqvSq8mW"
__v: 0
```

Could it be because the tdeenumber is not shown in the actual document? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: _"the page just loads forever"_... you're not using any of the `res` methods (like `res.send()` or `res.json()`) so that's not surprising

Comment: And you need to pass a callback, using `await` or `.exec()` to execute the update.

Answer (score 3):

You should've used `async/await` before db query also you're not returning a response to the call you receive.

Convert your controller like this and see the error correctly.

```
// Used async before the function to use await before the db query
router.post('/tdeecalculator', async (req, res) => {

//Wrapped your operation with try/catch block to catch error message and show it in console and response

    try {
        await User.updateOne({ email: "testtesttest@test.com" }, { $set: { tdeenumber: req.body.tdee } })
        res.send({ success: 1 });
        return;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.send({
            success: 0,
            error: error.message
        });
    }
});
```